# Image not retaining aspect ratio on mobile (iPhone)

Tags: html, css

I have seen solutions for aspect ratio using:

```
img{
   width: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

In my case, the CSS for the image in question is:

```
.schedule-img{
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--sf-primary);
  border-width: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

In Firefox's responsive design view for iPhone 8 plus, it looks like what I intend it to be:

[image: firefox]

But when I actually test it on my iPhone 8 plus, it looks like:

[image: iphone]

The width seems fine, but the height is stretched. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this kind of issue to support all resolutions is to make it as css background by that you save yourself lots of sweat. if the image is dynamically added you can added via `style` attribute as background.

You can then toy with background options if you are not satisfied with styling.

```
// example
background-image: url(yourimagepath);
background-size: cover;
// define height and width of parent container
width: 50%; // example
height: 320px; // example
```

Comment: How could I set the height of the parent container to always fit the dynamically added image?

Comment: @JustinSanter the containers would have same height but image inside will resize or reposition depends on ur background options